# Desktop Macro recorder Windows

Tags: windows, macros

I've heard of some software that let you "record" the actions you do in desktop  (based on images), so if you do something and "record it", then you `execute it` and what you recorded can be reproduced later on.

Do you know the name of this software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of software is called "Macro Recorders". Wikipedia has a [comparison article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_macro_recorder_software) of macro recorders.

Most known free macro recorder is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (great for automation not so great for recording).

Most known commercial one is [Jitbit Macro Recorder](http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/) (it can compile macros to EXE files).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools that can do this, but I can't tell from your description if there's a specific one you have in mind.

Wikipedia has a nice list of UI testing tools that would do this - some are open source, some closed. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools).

Answer (score 0):

> based on images

The only software I know of this kind is [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/). It's open source and cross-platform and has nice and simple to use IDE (screenshots can be found on the Internet).